# Download XML/Image from seperate thread

Tags: xml, multithreading, parsing, java-me

I am developing a Java ME application to download content from server. First time application load some content from local and first display contains more than one pages and we can move pages using right/left navigation. When a new page comes download will start and update the new content in current screen. when I move slowly from first to second page download will start and parse the `xml` and display content in screen. When I move fast from 1 to 2 to 3 page, from 1 to 2 start one `thread` for download at same time user move from 2 to 3 we will stop previous running `thread` and start a new thread for current screen.

Problems are:
1. How can I stop a running thread in Java ME? Now I have used one while loop in run method and give boolean value false, thread will run while boolean value becomes `true`. Is there any other way to stop a `thread` while running?

Answer (score 1):

Using a boolean variable is the best solution here. you can also use all of related regular methods in Thread class, but using those make your application unstable. some of them (like suspend) throws  some weird and unthrowable exceptions on SOME DEVICES!
I have an unrelated advice for you, don't use XMLs in j2me applications if at all possible. replace regular texts instead XMLs for faster and easier processing due to weak mobile processors.